# Git: Reference to other repositories using the "alternates" file does not work

Tags: git, repository

**Here is the setting:**

Background: I want to transfer a large part of my repository to an "archive" repository.

I have two bare repositories: `develop_new.git`, `archive.git`

I write into the file "C:\Git\Test\develop_new.git\objects\info\alternates" the following line:

```
/c/Git/Test/archive.git/objects
```

**Want I want to do:**

```
$ git replace --graft <commit_1> <commit_2>
```

in order to establish a history link between these two repositories.

commit_1 is the first commit in develop_new.git. commit_2 is the second last commit in archive.git.

**Problem:**

The following error occurs:

> error: object directory /c/Git/Test/archive.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.

despite the fact that the directory actually exists.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests, I had to use a relative path from the current repo's object store to the alternate object store.  That is, given

```
c/
  repo1/
    .git/
       ...
  repo2/
    .git/
      objects/
        info/
```

in `repo2/.git/objects/info/alternates` I could say

```
../../../repo1/.git/objects
```

but I could not say

```
/c/repo1/.git/objects
```

The docs do suggest that absolute paths should work locally, so I considered that maybe it was a path syntax mismatch (because I'm on Windows); and indeed

```
c:/repo1/.git/objects
```

works for me.

If you're going to access the repo remotely, absolute paths may again not work (per the docs); in that case you may want to look at using http-alternates

Comment: Hi, thanks. It actually worked with `../../archive.git/objects`!

Comment: Makes sense; if your repos are bare, you'd use one fewer `..`